# docValues Vs indexed field types for filter queries in Solr

Tags: solr, lucene

I need to add a field to Solr that would only be used for filtering.

i.e. `/query?q=*&fq=department:HR`

Which of these two definitions would work better and why?

```
<field name="department" type="string" indexed="true" docValues="false" />
```

```
<field name="department" type="string" indexed="false" docValues="true" />
```

Comment: Have you looked at https://solr.apache.org/guide/7_0/docvalues.html ?

Comment: @HectorCorrea yes, the documentation says "docValues" are more efficient for sorting, faceting and function queries. It is not clear to me whether that implies the same for filter queries.

Answer (score -1):

The below implementation is good for querying :

```
<field name="department" type="string" indexed="true" docValues="false" />
```

**Reason :**

**docValues="true" is required when you want to do faceting and sorting**. It will be the ideal and optimized case in that situation. **Since you only want querying docValues="false" is good.**

**indexed="true"** is good and it will query your results faster as **it will store the field in the indexed form which is faster than normal field**. So you'll be able to retrieve the results faster.